# [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU…Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module

Tags: linux, nvidia, slackware, gpu, graphic-card

I've installed **Bumblebee** with [Ryan McQuen's crazybee.sh script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryanpcmcquen/linuxTweaks/master/slackware/crazybee.sh), described [here](http://docs.slackware.com/howtos:hardware:nvidia_optimus#installing_bumblebee), and I'm actually able to startx successfully now (because Bumblebee uses the on-board Intel graphics by default), but when I invoke optirun to run a program with the Nvidia card, I get:

```
[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU
Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module
```

The "Turbo" light on the laptop, which indicates if the Nvidia card is on, turns on when I invoke optirun, which is good.

I've tried [the solutions to this "Cannot access secondary GPU" problem on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee#.5BERROR.5DCannot_access_secondary_GPU:_No_devices_detected), but to no avail…

Also, my trackpad freezes upon logging into KDE, so I'm thinking this might involve an issue in xorg.conf.

I'm running slackware64-current with the 3.14.27 kernel.

There's [a thread about the "failed to initialize kernel module" part of this issue **here**](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/ee-nvidia-0-failed-to-initialize-the-nvidia-kernel-module-250076/), but it's old, from 2004.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the nvidia-kernel package of Bumblebee did not install, due to my lacking libvdpau.

Comment: It would help if you described how you installed this and what the pkg name was, for example.